# Extracting Facebook profiles for offline use

Tags: java, facebook

I want to develop a simple java based application that can connect to facebook profile and saves the friend's profile in certain format for offline use. Later on if any changes is made offline , then when the connection is available the user profile should be updated automatically. Example, like if we posted any comment on his timeline, next time when the connection is available it should be updated to his profile. Now here are my questions:

1. Is this possible for a java desktop application?
2. Does facebook has any API we need here? if yes what API?
3. Can we maintain the date and time in the timeline as the date and time posted offline?

Give some details if possible. And if you don't understand any part just comment here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put the profile in a cache, perform actions on the profile while in offline mode and apply them when the user goes online.

The only issue will be to perserve datetime stamps, you are not in control over these on Facebook. So the datetimes will be from when the application goes "online".

Facebook got an API called Graph API, working directly towards the Graph API is really straight forward. But you can probably find a Java library to help you if you want.

I would recommend that you  start by reading some in the official documentation before moving forward with using a library.

Links that might be of interest:

- [Facebook Developers Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/)
- [Questions on Stackoverflow about similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+java)

*Note: The library linked to in Lix answer might be a bit out of date, Facebook are known for their rapid changes in their API and that library haven't been updated since 2010.*

Answer (score 0):

All of what you asked is indeed very possible.  [Here is a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to the facebook graph api reference.. There you will find all the information you need in order to implement your application.

A quick google search yeilds this result for a java sdk for facebook :

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/